# Google Signing Failed Error: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred (Using React Native without firebase)

Tags: react-native, google-oauth

I am trying to get basic information of user once user clicks on the Google sign in button like his username and email. I want to do this without the use of firebase, however, I am getting error saying "A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred". Below is my code.

```
const MainApp = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId:
        'XXX',
      offlineAccess: true,
      forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    });

    isSignedIn();
  }, []);

  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log('due--->', userInfo);
      setUser(userInfo);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Message--->', error.message);
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        // user cancelled the sign-in process
        Alert.alert('user cancelled the sign-in process');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
        Alert.alert('Sign in is in progress already');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        // play services not available or outdated
        Alert.alert('play services not available or outdated');
      } else {
        // some other error occurred
        Alert.alert(error + ' err');
      }
    }
  };

  const isSignedIn = async () => {
    const isSignedIn = await GoogleSignin.isSignedIn();
    if (!!isSignedIn) {
      getCurrentUserInfo();
    } else {
      console.log('Please login');
    }
  };

  
};
```

`Error Message: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred`

Comment: I was finally able to solve this using steps mentioned here: https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues/932

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I had the same issue. The solution is to add more credentials in the google API console. You need to add the credentials not only for web (which you use while signing in) but also for Android using the SHA1 from your keystore file. It just needs to be there.

Also make sure you are adding one for your debug and another for release version, if they use different keystore files.

What helped me find it out was: https://dev.to/suyashdev/google-authsignin-in-react-native-without-firebase-43n